# i am getting HTTPError('502 Server Error: Bad Gateway for 'https://myurl") using locust with python

Tags: python, testing, load-testing, locust

while executing locust load test i have faced the mentioned issue and I have checked in my application insights there is no errors. so please help me how to resolve find the exact cause of this issue

```
    @task(1)
        def test(self):
            r = self.client.post("url",data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers, catch_response=False)
            self.interrupt()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot more Locust can tell you: the server/URL you requested returned a 502 error. You can check exactly what URL locust ran against using `print(r.url)` (if it is literally `https://myurl` like you say in the title then that is your problem :)